# Query occurrences within a comma separated list

Tags: mysql

I have a table where one column may contain comma separated values e.g.

```
| Date ...........| Methods .....|
-
| 2014/10/01 .|  A ................|
-
| 2014/11/01 .|  C ................|
-
| 2014/08/01 .|  A,B .............|
-
| 2015/09/01 .|  C ................|
-
| 2015/11/01 .|  C, A ............|
-
```

I would like to output a summary with a count based on Year and Method so that the results produced would be

```
**2014: A = 2,  B = 1, C = 1** and **2015: A = 1, B = 0, C = 2**
```

So without the comma separated list it would be a simple group by but with the list this would just result in A,B being treated as a separate entry and not a +1 for both A and B. Is this possible?

I hope that makes sense and the 'table' is clear.

Comment: may you please tell why do you have comma separated list?

Comment: The comma separated list is used for other areas of the database and has only been for recording information now we'd like to report on it so the need to do the above type query.

Comment: Did not try the group by as I know that won't work, I've seen a solution that involves creating a temporary table to break apart the comma separated list but that seems overkill for what I want. Really looking to see if there is another way to do it via MySQL before I just process the data via PHP using arrays and then array count.

Comment: There is no other way to solve your problem. You can use the same approach (temp table) with just sql command. That's what a bad design causes, overkill solutions to simple problems. Your design should be something like: tableDates, tablesDatesMethods (iddateFK, idMethod), Methods

Comment: Either normalize your data, or don't bother using an RDBMS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `SPLIT_STR` function and below query :

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Query :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y'),SPLIT_STR(dats,',',1) AS m1, SPLIT_STR(dats,',',2) AS m2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY date, Methods
```

Comment: @rsphorler : Check the answer and let me know if it fixed your issue

Comment: Thank you that seems to look quite promising with the initial test, now just need to work it into the real data. First time I've used a Function so need to check how that will work but it is working on my test server.

Comment: @rsphorler :) great it worked for you. Go ahead and test it with real data. Using functions in mysql query will surely a great solution. Also let me know if there is any issue. Do accept the answer as well;)

Comment: Sadly it does not produce the expected counts I need to see if this is because of the data (some old imported data is A, B rather than A,B) but even for those which are this years data I'm not getting the counts expected.

Comment: It does not seem to include the Method when it is the last element of a list that what seems to cause the discrepancy

Comment: @rsphorler Please check my updated query. It will return year with m1 and m2. After that you can loop and create an array to get expected result

Comment: Ok with that method I would get the results for each position within the list, so its as easy to do with PHP which is what I will go for in the end. Many thanks for your help.